Customizing MudDataGrid DataGridFilterMode.ColumnFilterMenu behavior
There are a few tweaks I would like to implement to DataGridFilterMode.ColumnFilterMenu in MudBlazor.
1) After the user types some text and they hit Enter I would like that to simulate clicking on the Filter Button. Please see screenshot below.

2) When the Popover Opens I would like the cursor to set focus directly into the value field.

3) By Default I would like the Filter type to be Starts With instead of Contains.

